# Is it possible to apply both 'and' and 'or' filters in a single request with Google Analytics run report API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

How to use and, or filter expression both  in one request : Google Analytics run report API.

I have a one scenario where  I have to filter the result on the basis of  dimensions or metrics
where  A or B and C or D. Here A ,B ,C and D are the conditions which are the combinations of metrics or dimensions.

as per API documentation  expr can be only one of the following:
or, and.

how to get the result for given conditions.

could you please provide me sample request if it's possible

Thanks and would like hear back.

You can find the sample request which I have tried and getting the exception as  "message": "Invalid value at 'dimension_filter' (oneof), oneof field 'expr' is already set. Cannot set 'andGroup'",
In same request if I can include and , or condition for metric filters as well.

```
{
   "dateRanges":[
      {
         "startDate":"2019-01-01",
         "endDate":"2023-05-02",
         "name":"0"
      }
   ],
   "keepEmptyRows":"TRUE",
   "metrics":[
      {
         "name":"Conversions"
      },
      {
         "name":"EngagementRate"
      },
      {
         "name":"EngagedSessions"
      },
      {
         "name":"EventCount"
      },
      {
         "name":"NewUsers"
      },
      {
         "name":"TotalRevenue"
      },
      {
         "name":"TotalUsers"
      }
   ],
   "dimensions":[
      {
         "name":"Browser"
      }
   ],
   "dimensionFilter":{
      "orGroup":{
         "expressions":[
            {
               "filter":{
                  "fieldName":"Browser",
                  "stringFilter":{
                     "matchType":"CONTAINS",
                     "value":"moz"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "filter":{
                  "fieldName":"Browser",
                  "stringFilter":{
                     "matchType":"CONTAINS",
                     "value":"test"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "andGroup":{
         "expressions":[
            {
               "filter":{
                  "fieldName":"Browser",
                  "stringFilter":{
                     "matchType":"CONTAINS",
                     "value":"ed"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "filter":{
                  "fieldName":"Browser",
                  "stringFilter":{
                     "matchType":"CONTAINS",
                     "value":"ch"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "offset":"0",
   "limit":"10000"
}
```

Comment: Can you make different requests for each `OR` condition and then join results at your backend?

Comment: Hi @Justinas ,
Thanks for the suggestion. As this will become  a very costly operation if I am making a different request for each 'or', 'and' conditions. I am looking the solution where in one API request I can include  both 'and' and 'or' conditions.

Comment: Do you need in programing languages such as java or you are working directly in your analytics.google profile?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Community ,
for or conditions the sample API request will look like below request.

"dimensionFilter": {
    "orGroup": {
      "expressions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "fieldName": "Browser",
            "stringFilter": {
              "matchType": "CONTAINS",
              "value": "ch"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },

is it possible both andgroup , orgroup in one request.

Comment: Hi @ShilaMosammami,
it will be very helpful  if you can provide me sample body request of the API. So I can implement that in our java code

Answer (score 1):

This is a java and / or filter for what I created,Remember filtering of events and dimensions should be in a compatible way. Log in [Here](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) and play with your events, dimensions and metrics to find out.

of course, you can change date range as well.

```
`GoogleCredentials credentials =
                    GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialsJsonPath));

            BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings =
                    BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                    .build();    

            try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData =
                    BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings)) {



                RunReportRequest request =
                        RunReportRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setProperty("properties/" + your propertyId)
                        .addDateRanges(DateRange.newBuilder().setStartDate("365daysAgo").setEndDate("yesterday"))
                         


                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("date")) 
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("eventName"))
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("customEvent:XXXXX")) // instead of XXXXX write your custom dimension
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("fullPageUrl")) // this is not a customised dimension



                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventCount"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventsPerSession"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventValue"))


                        .setDimensionFilter(FilterExpression.newBuilder()
                                .setOrGroup(FilterExpressionList.newBuilder()
                                        .addExpressions(FilterExpression.newBuilder()
                                                .setFilter(Filter.newBuilder()
                                                        .setFieldName("eventName")
                                                        .setStringFilter(Filter.StringFilter.newBuilder()
                                                                .setMatchType(Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.EXACT)
                                                                .setValue("your 1st event to filter"))))  // for example page_view
                                        .addExpressions(FilterExpression.newBuilder()
                                                .setFilter(Filter.newBuilder()
                                                        .setFieldName("eventName")
                                                        .setStringFilter(Filter.StringFilter.newBuilder()
                                                                .setMatchType(Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.EXACT)
                                                                .setValue("your 2nd event")))))
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                .setAndGroup(FilterExpressionList.newBuilder().addExpressions(FilterExpression.newBuilder()
                                                .setFilter(Filter.newBuilder()
                                                        .setFieldName("eventName")
                                                        .setStringFilter(Filter.StringFilter.newBuilder()
                                                                .setMatchType(Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.EXACT)
                                                                .setValue("your 3rd event"))))))

                        .setLimit(100000)
                        .build();

                 
                RunReportResponse response = analyticsData.runReport(request);`
```

The Request Body as an example could be like this:

```
property: "properties/write your propertId"
dimensions {
  name: "date"
}
dimensions {
  name: "eventName"
}
dimensions {
  name: "customEvent:category" // my custom dimensions is category that should be written after "customEvent:" 
}
dimensions {
  name: "customEvent:action" // my custom dimensions is action that should be written after "customEvent:" 
}
dimensions {
  name: "customEvent:label" // my custom dimensions is label that should be written after "customEvent:" 
}
metrics {
  name: "eventCount"
}
metrics {
  name: "eventsPerSession"
}
metrics {
  name: "eventValue"
}
date_ranges {
  start_date: "2023-05-22" 
  end_date: "2023-05-23"
}
dimension_filter {
  or_group {
    expressions {
      filter {
        field_name: "eventName"
        string_filter {
          match_type: EXACT
          value: "Something"  
        }
      }
    }
    expressions {
      filter {
        field_name: "eventName"
        string_filter {
          match_type: EXACT
          value: "myCustomEventName " // as an example I wrote my customised event name
        }
      }
    }
    expressions {
      and_group {
        expressions {
          filter {
            field_name: "eventName"
            string_filter {
              match_type: EXACT
              value: "SOMETHING"   
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide me a sample request body of an API  here?

Comment: you can print it in java, after sending the request just add System.out.println(request .toString());

Comment: I am not sure if you have tried or not as per API documentation it can be only one expr https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression#FilterExpressionList
from the start, I am trying to figure out the request body sample example. I  have tried in Postman but the API is throwing exceptions as 
 "message": "Invalid value at 'dimension_filter' (one of), one of field 'expr' is already set. Cannot set 'andGroup'",

Comment: your help is really appreciated but the example you have given here is wrong as per the API documentation 
"dimensionFilter": {
    "orGroup": {
{
  "expressions": [
    {
      object (FilterExpression)
    }
  ]
}
}

and if we use andgroup expression along with orgroup it will throw the exception if we use more than one condition as mentioned in the API documentation
Have you tested this?

Comment: would you write what exactly you write? because my example is based on my project and my custom event and dimensions, which it means that you should have created them at least 48 hours ago. and yes, in my case I have the response. the request is printed by JaVA.

Comment: It's not allowing me to add more text as StackOverflow has limitations else I have provided you a complete sample request for API.
 It throws an exception  when both andGroup, orGroup expressions conditions are available 
        "message": "Invalid value at 'dimension_filter' (oneof), oneof field 'expr' is already set. Cannot set 'andGroup'",

Comment: please add it to your question, you can modify the question

Comment: I have added a sample format in the description which I have tried.

Comment: @VivekShukla The dimensionFilter part of the request specifies that the results should include data where the Browser dimension contains either the string “test” or the string “ch” (orGroup), and also contains both the string “ed” and the string “ch” (andGroup). In other words, the filter can be translated into the following logical condition: if (Browser contains "test" OR Browser contains "ch") AND (Browser contains "ed" AND Browser contains "ch")
Does it sound logical to you a Browser name is called ch and ed at the same time? The logic of your request is Wrong.

Comment: @VivekShukla,  in this specific example you should use only orGroup for this Browser dimension.

Comment: I have just provided the sample request if we can include both andgroup,  orgroup expressions in one request. As API throws the exception.

Comment: this is the sample request I have different conditions. For that, I need both andgroup , orgroup expressions in one request.

Comment: @VivekShukla as I provided for you, of course you can  Change your field_name. since I do not you what dimensions you have active I cannot help you more. pay attention that there are some dimensions in conflict with others.

Comment: I have already tried with this request but it has a syntax error.